# How to divide response by months and add counter with Java API in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, counter, aggregation, java

I have several thousand of docs in elasticsearch with different time and three serviceId's. Is it possible to divide all these docs by month with counter?
Document model:

```
{
    "dateTime" : "2011-03-13T11:34:14.869Z",
    "organizationId" : "1a4b7625-dcec-4326-b7dc-96e038b31d0b",
    "accountId" : "a9bfcced-ddaa-477c-8021-18364ac320ee",
    "processInstanceId" : "711e73cb-1286-461f-810f-d5791f71101f",
    "serviceConfigurationId" : "e8be10e8-2ba2-4365-bfb0-96052d90be7e",
    "clusterId" : "542096b3-3982-4d4b-bce1-44b1f988cf7f",
    "serviceId" : "asdf"
}
```

I'm doing a SearchRequest with range (for example a year), and expect it to do something like this:

```
{
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "Jc0H03AB-y_MhSAimo7v",
    "_score": null,
    "_month": {
        "Jan": [
            {
                "serviceId": "asdf",
                "counter": 4
            },
            {
                "serviceId": "zxcv",
                "counter": 9
            }
        ],
        "Feb":[
        {
                "serviceId": "asdf",
                "counter": 12
            },
            {
                "serviceId": "zxcv",
                "counter": 11
            }
        ], etc
    }
}
```

I found how to create a range query with Java API.

```
RangeQueryBuilder rangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("dateTime").from(LocalDateTime.parse("2011-11-09T10:30")).to(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-11-09T10:30")).timeZone("Z");
sourceBuilder.query(rangeQueryBuilder);
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
client().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Maybe it's impossible and I'm wasting my time trying to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Range query will return documents where dateTime falls within givens. You cannot group them by months in query part. This can be done using [date_histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) and [top_hits aggregationb](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter_year": {  --> filter documents which fall in given interval
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "dateTime": {
            "gte": "2011-01-01",
            "lte": "2011-12-31"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "month": {
          "date_histogram": {  --> group documents on monthly interval
            "field": "dateTime",
            "format": "MMM",
            "interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "documents": {
              "top_hits": { --> return documents  under months
                "_source": [
                  "clusterId"
                ],
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```